# If conditional won't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've never seen that in my life, my conditional do not want to work, that's my JavaScript code:

```
//Remove todos os elementos relacionados a frete
function removeAllFrete(callback){
    var a = $(".remove-frete").length;
    for (i = 0; i < a; ++i) {
        $(".remove-frete").each(function(){
            $(this).animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, function(){
                $(this).slideUp(function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            });
            if ( i == a - 1 && typeof(callback) === "function" ){
                return(callback());
            }
        });
    }
}

//Exibe o formulário de busca de CEP
function buscarCEP(msg, callback){

    function showSearchForm(){
        el = $("<div class=\"frete-form remove-frete\"><div class=\"form-group no-margin-last\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"text-input\" placeholder=\"Endereço\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"text-input\" placeholder=\"Cidade\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"text-input\" placeholder=\"Estado\"><input id=\"frete-search-trigger\" type=\"submit\" class=\"submit-input\" value=\"Pesquisar\"></div></div>")

        $(".frete-cont").append(el);

        el.slideDown(function(){
            $(this).animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, function(){
                $("#frete-search-trigger").on("click", function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    removeAllFrete();
                });
            });
        });
    }

    if ( msg != null){
        var elR = $("<div class=\"frete-no-result remove-frete\">" + msg + "</div>");

        $(".frete-cont").append(elR);

        elR.slideDown(function(){
            $(this).animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, function(){
                showSearchForm();
            });
        });
    } else{
        showSearchForm();
    }
}

$("#frete-forget-trigger").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log("a");
    if( $(".frete-form").length ){
        console.log("1");
        removeAllFrete();
    } else{
        removeAllFrete(function(){
            console.log("2");
            buscarCEP(null);
        });
    }
});
```

Here you can find a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5hjhxm09/

Any idea what could be?

---

My mistake, check my answer below...

Here you can find a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5hjhxm09/4/

Comment: You forget to say which if _fails_ to execute...

Comment: What are you expecting to happen that's not happening? `$(".frete-form").length` is 0, so the else branch runs, calling  `removeAllFrete` correctly.

Comment: I'm always amazed when I see foreign code still in English syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the conditional, but at the for cycle:

```
$(".remove-frete").length === 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
click  $("#frete-forget-trigger")
```

then

```
 console.log("a");

// $(".frete-form").length =0
```

then run

```
removeAllFrete(function(){
        console.log("2");
        buscarCEP(null);
    });
}
```

then run removeAllFrete

```
var a = $(".remove-frete").length;

// a = 0


for (i = 0; i < a; ++i) {
        ...

}
```

END

everything is ok , click and console a

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in a conditional inside the `removeAllFrete()` function:

```
if ( i == a - 1 && typeof(callback) === "function" ){
    return(callback());
}
```

When I changed the trigger for the following conditional, it worked properly:

```
$("#frete-forget-trigger").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log("a");
    if( $(".remove-frete").length ){
        console.log("1");
        removeAllFrete();
    } else{
        console.log("2");
        buscarCEP(null);
    }
});
```